# Connect PySpark to Kafka from Docker container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have a Kafka cluster that I'm managing with Docker.

I have a container where I'm running the broker and another one where I run the pyspark program which is supposed to connect to the kafka topic inside the broker container.

If I run the pyspark script in my local laptop everything runs perfectly but if I try to run the same code from inside the pyspark container I get the following error:

```
AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide"
```

Does anybody know how can I access the Kafka topic running in a docker container from another external container?

This is the PySpark code

```
df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
    .option("subscribe", "tweets") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.1.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: "true"
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: "anonymous"

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.1.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:latest
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-6.1.0.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.1.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER: "connect:8083"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021

  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.1.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:6.1.0
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  ksql-datagen:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:6.1.0
    hostname: ksql-datagen
    container_name: ksql-datagen
    depends_on:
      - ksqldb-server
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    command: "bash -c 'echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... && \
      cub kafka-ready -b broker:29092 1 40 && \
      echo Waiting for Confluent Schema Registry to be ready... && \
      cub sr-ready schema-registry 8081 40 && \
      echo Waiting a few seconds for topic creation to finish... && \
      sleep 11 && \
      tail -f /dev/null'"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST: schema-registry
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT: 8081

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.1.0
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.11.2
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  pyspark:
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest
    hostname: pyspark
    container_name: pyspark
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    #volumes:
    #  - pySpark: pySpark/
    depends_on:
      - broker

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
    driver: local
  pySpark:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Did you happen to download the Kafka jars on your local Spark installation? Or change the Spark config to include the Kafka packages for all jobs? That would explain why it wouldn't work in the container

Comment: I installed Spark locally with conda and it works,I didn't download any Kafka Jars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems in your setup:

- You don't add the package for Kafka support as described in [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html).  It's either needs to be added when starting `pyspark`, or when initializing session, something like this (change `3.0.1` to version that is used in your jupyter container):

```py
SparkSession.builder.appName('my_app')\
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1')\
    .getOrCreate()
```

- you're connecting to `"localhost:9092"`, but it's incorrect inside the container because container with Jupyter has its own `localhost` that is different from Kafka container's localhost.  You need to use name `broker` instead, as it's declared in the docker-compose.yaml

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
For the first point I was just wondering why if I need to specify the spark jars my program was running fine outside my docker container without specifying them.

Comment: For the second point I tried changing "localhost" to "broker" already but it gave the same error unfortunately

Comment: until you fix first point, 2nd won't work, because you don't have necessary package added to Spark

Comment: Thank you, I will try fixing the first and then let you know!